# What for incompatibility between babel-proposal-decorators and typescript-decorator?

Tags: typescript, babeljs, ts-jest, typescript-decorator, jest-expo

I recently rewrite [CyriacBr/class-fixtures-factory](https://github.com/CyriacBr/class-fixtures-factory) with updating libraries version at https://github.com/MOCHI-inc-JAPAN/class-fixtures-factory.
I succeeded running it in ts-jest environment, but switch jest-expo, doesn't work. I suspect decorator's not processed properly in jest-expo for incompatibility of typescript's one. Decorator looks working both environment, but not properly reflect the metadata from property type, in typescript decorator metadata includes typeClassification, but in jest-expo(maybe babel-proposal-decorators) doesn't. Why this difference happens and, how do I adjust jest-expo behavior to ts-jest? In addition, we want to use this library in expo environment because our products have some snapshot tests.

[This repository](https://github.com/tkow/jest-expo-env-poc) can reproduce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    "plugins": [
      ["babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata"],
    ],
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

I can work it only to add babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata. It enables this to store metadata like typescript compiler.